# Cannot send/receive number through USB to Arduino to control a motor

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I'm having a project to use pyserial to send a number to an Arduino. This number is RPM (round per minute). Arduino will receive this number to control the motor (in here I use PID Controller) and then send the number Arduino received back to Python console. The problem is, I tried to send float number to Arduino, but it receives nothing. Here is the problem:

```cpp
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <Encoder.h>
#define A 2 //Encoder pins
#define B 3
Encoder encoder(2,3);
//Config pins for motor control:
int pinAIN1 = 9; //Direction
int pinAIN2 = 8; //Direction
int pinPWMA = 5; //Speed
int pinSTBY = 4; //Stanby
float receive;
float tsamp = 0.01;
float xung = 0;
float last_xung = 0;
float current_speed = 0;
float ref_speed ; //The reference speed
float error = 0;
float last_error = 0;
float PID,last_PID;
float Kp =0.15 , Ki =0, Kd = 0.01;

void dotocdo()
{
  if ( ref_speed >= 0)
   {
   digitalWrite(pinAIN1, 1);
   digitalWrite(pinAIN2, 0);
   analogWrite(pinPWMA, PID);
   }

   if ( ref_speed < 0)
   {
     digitalWrite(pinAIN1, 0);
     digitalWrite(pinAIN2, 1);
     analogWrite(pinPWMA, abs(PID));
   }
  float P;
  static float I,D;
  current_speed = 60*(xung-last_xung)/(tsamp*374*4);
  last_xung = xung; 
  Serial.println(current_speed);

  error=abs(ref_speed)-abs(current_speed);
  P = Kp*error;
  D = Kd*(error - last_error)/tsamp;
  I = Ki*error*tsamp; 
  PID = last_PID + P + I + D;
  last_error = error;
  last_PID = PID;
  if (PID >= 255) {PID = 255;}
  if (PID <= -255) {PID = -255;}
}
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(pinPWMA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinAIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinAIN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinSTBY, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A, INPUT);
  pinMode(B, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(pinSTBY, 1);
  Timer1.initialize(10000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(dotocdo);
}

void loop()
{

    if (Serial.available())
    {
     receive= Serial.parseFloat();
     ref_speed=receive;
     Serial.println(receive);
    }
   xung=encoder.read();

}
```

And here is the Python code on Raspberry:

```py
import time
import socket
import sys
import serial
import struct

UNO_1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)

while (1):
    n=float(25)
    UNO_1.write(bytes(b'%f'%n))
    receive=UNO_1.readline()
    print(receive)
```

This is the error (Arduino receives nothing):

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: There is no error message?

Comment: Maybe try to save the msg as a string and print it to see what you are actually getting? parseFloat will default to zero if it finds anything except float

Comment: @Hackerman : Yup, there is no error message

Comment: @TheEngineer I did tried to change it to string, my arduino code changed to this:
char CurrentData;
String receive="";
int ref_speed;
 while(Serial.available()>0)
   {
      CurrentData= Serial.read();
      if (CurrentData=='.')
      {
        ref_speed=receive.toInt();
        receive="";
      }
      else
      {
        if (CurrentData!=0)
        {
        receive += (char)CurrentData;
        }
        
      }
      Serial.println(ref_speed);
   }

After that in my python console, i got result:
b'25\r\n'
b'0.00\r\n'
b0.00\r\n'
b'25\r\n'
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Has any communication worked before?
2. Double-check your connections (swapped TX and RX, forgot GND)
3. Try using a serial terminal (I think pyserial has a demo included) to send data manually.
4. Your Python script may just be timing out.
5. Your Python script might be sending too many zeroes or control characters that [`Serial.parseFloat()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat) does not like (it stops if it does not like something).
6. Alternativley, just get started with echo programs that don't actually try to parse numbers to see if any data comes through: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336098/1619432).